# What is the best match of hadoop version with java version

Tags: java, hadoop

Please Help me.  What are the exact Properties of  the listed xml files... or Please Tell me the best compatible version of hadoop with java version...?

I have used

```
hadoop 2.9.1 
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

I am so tired to modify the following file

1. yarn-site.xml
2. hdfs-site.xml
3. mapred-site.xml
4. core-site.xml

I can't run the simple wordcount program.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop requires Java 8, for now

You can refer to the Hadoop Apache site which describes all properties in those files along with their defaults